# Do I need to use jQuery Map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm including jQuery via this Google CDN:

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
```

The only reason I'm using jQuery is because of Bootstrap, which I'm loading from this CDN:

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js
```

The problem is that whenever my page loads, the slowest file to come is `jquery.min.map`. which returns a 304 GET and takes over 50ms to load. I understand Javascript maps are to debug obfuscated/minified code? Not sure why I'd need this in a production application.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use twitter bootstrap without jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14608681/can-i-use-twitter-bootstrap-without-jquery)

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I think you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - The title says `Do I need to use jQuery Map` not `Do I need to use jQuery with Bootstrap`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is being loaded by your debug tools in the browser. You can disable it in the options.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but will others' browsers have this disabled by default?

Comment: @Carpetfizz No, of course, see the second line of the jQuery file, `//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map`, if you remove this line browser  doesn't load the source map, but for doing this you should not use CDN, as you can't modify the file. That being said, not all the users use their browsers' console and loading source maps doesn't hurt your app.

Comment: Okay cool thanks. I thought it loaded even without the console open.

Answer (score 3):

[No one says you need it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/). They are requested by your browser's debugger tools.